# Como utilizar AJAX para atualizar elementos HTML sem carregamento?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Alguém sabe me indicar um bom artigo que explique bem o uso de AJAX? Ou até mesmo que possa explicar melhor seu funcionamento?
Obrigada!

Comment: Oi Jessy, bem-vinda ao site. Veja se os links acima te ajudam. Se não resolverem, avise aqui.

Comment: Ajudou bastante, obrigada ❤